# How to get a particular value from file by batch script?

Tags: batch-file

I have a file abc.txt which has the below content

```
3922 [main] INFO  com.informatica.saas.utilities.task.ICSTask  - Submitted run of the task: taskId=000YKG0N00000000002N, taskRunId=\
```

I want to extract the word `000YKG0N00000000002N` and store this value in a variable to use it further in my script.

I tried using the below code :

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (abc.txt) & for %%A in ("taskId=" "%") do echo Value: %%~A
```

Error I am getting:

> %%A was unexpected at this time

Please help me resolve the issue

Comment: From the command line, use: `for /F "tokens=2 delims==," %A in (abc.txt) do echo Value: %A` or put this line in a .BATch file and double the percent-signs: `for /F "tokens=2 delims==," %%A in (abc.txt) do echo Value: %%A`

Answer (score 0):

You can give the following code a try :

```bat
@echo off
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%A in ('Type abc.txt') do ( 
    for /F "tokens=1 delims=," %%B in ('echo %%A') do (
        Set "IDTask=%%B"
    )
)
echo TaskID = [%IDTask%]
pause
```

***EDIT :*** Another code inspired from Gerhard Barnard answer :

```bat
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
@for /f "tokens=2 delims=:," %%i in ('type abc.txt') do ( 
    @set%%i 
    REM To remove Space into Variable
    Set "taskID=!taskID: =!"
    echo taskID = [!taskID!]
)   
pause
```

Comment: There js not a need to get rid of the space as the space is not part of the value.

Comment: Hi ..Above solution worked , but there are two lines coming in the above code. 0015FL0Z0000000000R6  
0015FL0Z0000000000R6  . How can I adjust my code to get only one line in my output

Comment: abc.txt is dynamically created and can contain many lines like this. 2807 [main] INFO  com.informatica.saas.utilities.task.ICSTask  - Submitted run of the task: taskId=0015FL0Z0000000000R6, taskRunId=20784
https://use4.cd-us.abc.com/     taskId=0015FL0Z0000000000R6&runId=20784. So, there are two "taskId=" in this file getting created. How can i fetch distinct value of task id .. I have to use distinct value of task id in the next steps of my code

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps as simple as:

```
@for /f "tokens=2 delims=:," %%i in ('type abc.txt') do @set%%i
echo %taskID%
```

or if the token shifted as per you new question:

```
@for /f "tokens=3 delims=:," %%i in ('type abc.txt') do @set%%i
echo %taskID%
```