# How can I get unique records from in the below case

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to run a script where I am trying to find a value from a file.
File is :

```
8009 [main] INFO  com.utilities.task.ICSTask  - Submitted run of the task: taskId=0015FL0Z0000000000R6, taskRunId=20789
https://use4.dm-us.com/saas/api/v2/activity/activityLog?taskId=0015FL0Z0000000000R6&runId=20789
```

Code I wrote is :

```
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
@for /f "tokens=2 delims=:," %%i in ('type abc.txt') do ( 
    @set%%i 
    REM To remove Space into Variable
    Set "taskID=!taskID: =!"
    echo !taskID!  >> def.txt
)
```

Result I am getting is :

> 0015FL0Z0000000000R6
>   0015FL0Z0000000000R6

I want to get unique value of `0015FL0Z0000000000R6` in `def.txt` file as a result. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Open up a Command Prompt window and enter `"%__AppDir__%find.exe" /?`, read the output, then run `"%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" /?` and do the same. Choose the most appropriate of those commands for your circumstances, and if it fails to work as intended, let us know, by updating your posted script accordingly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a particular value from file by batch script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58786621/how-to-get-a-particular-value-from-file-by-batch-script)

Comment: Can you clarify if you're wanting to isolate, **1.** Every unique `taskId` value from the file? **2.** Each unique `taskId` value from the 'submission' lines? or **3.** Each unique `taskId` from the 'URL' lines?

Comment: besides the fact that there aren't any spaces to be removed  - you introduce them later with your `echo` command.

Comment: @stephan OP got that from Hackoo on the [previous answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58786621/how-to-get-a-particular-value-from-file-by-batch-script)

Comment: There will be only one taskId but I am getting this is multiple lines. I want to retrive the taskId which is same for a flow.

Comment: You have four questions open for this very issue. Each of them received at least one working answer. What's wrong with them? If none of those answers solves your issue, maybe you should explain *why*/*how* they don't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

> There will be only one taskId but I am getting this is multiple lines.
>   I want to retrive the taskId which is same for a flow.

you have only one taskId, but you have two lines in the text file, which means, your loop is executed two times. And as `taskid` isn't overwritten the second time, it still holds the value from the first time.

Change `... in ('type abc.txt') do ...` to `... in ('type abc.txt^|find "taskId="') do ...` to filter `abc.txt` to the relevant line only.

Also, you do `echo !taskID!  >> def.txt`, which adds two trailing spaces. I slightly changed the redirection syntax to avoid that.

That changes your complete code to:

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:," %%i in ('type abc.txt^|find "taskId=') do ( 
    @set%%i 
    REM To remove Space into Variable
    Set "taskID=!taskID: =!"
    >>def.txt echo !taskID!
)
```